# How to put pandas DataFrame using pyodbc in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database, dataframe

With the pandas DataFrame called 'data' (see code), I want to put it into a table in SQL Server. How should I do this?

I read something on the internet with `data.to_sql`, so I tried a little with this function. However, it gives me an error message (see error message). It probably has to do with the argument `con = conn`. I don't know how to fix this. The error message says something about SQLite. I am not very advanced in using SQL, so I do not understand all errors.

Do you have any ideas? I think the `conn` is the only problem. The rest works fine.

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2018.

Ty in advance.

Error message:

```
Exception has occurred: DatabaseError 
Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': 
('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); 
[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

```
def connection():
    try:
        #connect to network database
        conn = None
        conn = db.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=xxsql.database.windows.net;'
                      'Database=xx;' 
                      'uid=xx;' 
                      'pwd=xx;')
    
        #if connected do
        if conn is not None:
            print("The connection is established")
            sql_query = 'select top 20 * from xx'
          
            #read table into dataframe
            #make a dataframe with records from table
            dfObj  = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, conn)
            
            #inspect result
            print(dfObj)
            
            #read into list
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql_query)
        
            #put cursor to list
            cursor_list = list(cursor.fetchall())
       
            #make copy so that we wont change original data
            table = cursor_list.copy()
                                  
            bibliography = Extract(table)
            data = pd.DataFrame(bibliography)

            #convert it to SQL
            data.to_sql('ExtractedBib', con = conn, if_exists = 'append') #????
    
    except db.Error as e:
        print(e)
    
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            print("The connection is closed")
        else: 
            print("No connection established")

def main():
    connection()

main()
```

Comment: You have the above code, so please describe what's wrong with it. Do you have some errors? So post them in your question as plain text. Do you have result that is not you wanted to see? Please, provide your results and the description of what do you want. Also I cannot get the reason to pull the data twice after you've fetched (all) it as dataframe. Just turn it to list in application code.

Comment: I get the error message: Exception has occurred: DatabaseError
Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)"). However, I'm using SQLSMS. I think the error pops up because of the 'con = conn' in de function to_sql.

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65280588/edit) your question and add this error to question. Error clearly says you that table `sqlite_master` does not exists in database. And it is obvious, because SQL Server is not SQLite. But I don't see any reference to that table in your code.

Comment: So, does that mean that this function only works for SQLite and not for Server? Is there a similar function that works for Server?

Comment: Do I need to first make an empty table in SQL Server?

Comment: Which function? You issue a select from table that does not exists, there's no any feature in select or database or anything else. Please, update your code with exact statements you use and add the python traceback after error.

Comment: Did it work out?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sqlalchemy` instead.

```
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
               "xxsql+pyodbc://uid:pwd@Server/Database",
               echo=False)
...

data.to_sql('ExtractedBib', con=engine, if_exists = 'append')
```

Just change the template values into your database values (uid, pwd etc.)